# Sending Bluetooth Advertising Packets Programmatically

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, bluetooth

I'm setting an application in other to scan smartphones each other, a kind of bluetooth scanner.

As we all know it's not programmatically possible to get the MAC Address of the scanner itself, but we have the MAC address of other phones (the scanned).

In the other hand I generate a UUID when installing the application to identify the scanner in the data base.

I'd like to associate each of mac addresses got by scanners to the corresponding UUID in the database.

So I was looking for the better and easy way to do it, and I thought maybe in addition, each phone should send advertising packets with its UUID so that the other phones (scanners) can get that with other informations.

I don't know if this is possible using mobile development frameworks like flutter/dart... Else what could be the best way to associate MAC addresses to phone UUID in this case?

Comment: On iOS you can't get the MAC address of the other device either.

Comment: Also, are you aware of this - https://www.apple.com/au/newsroom/2020/04/apple-and-google-partner-on-covid-19-contact-tracing-technology/

Comment: @Paulw11 when you say "on iOS you can't get the MAC address of other device either", do you mean scanner or scanned? The limite is on the scanner phone or the phone being scanned?

Comment: Yes @Paulw11 I'm aware of that Google and Apple announcement. Do these specifications mean communication is between android and ios only or between : android <-> android, ios <-> ios, android <-> ios?

Comment: Neither the scanning nor scanned MAC address is available on iOS. Core Bluetooth returns an identifier for discovered devices; this identifier is unique per device pair (ie Phone A sees a different identifier for phone B than phone C sees for phone B).  The specifications are cross-platform; that is why they are working together

Comment: Cool @Paulw11, I understand, but if like you say "Phone A sees a different identifier for phone B than phone C sees for phone B", there could be doublon in objects database, as phone B is seen two times differently... Right? They identifiers are hardcoded in the OS, or one could programmatically implement bluetooth advertising so that we can uniquely persist and identify each phone wherever it's located?

Comment: That is right.  iOS calculates the identifier for the device.  It is consistent for any pair of devices (discoverer and discovered).  You can't control the identifier.  You could try and add custom data to the bluetooth advertisement.  You should also be aware that if you are working on a Covid-19 tracing app, Apple will only approve apps that are submitted by governments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211691/discussion-between-nixmind-and-paulw11).